# Forming a 2D table with conditions with a function

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I have a function which can be represented as a weighted sum of parameters f(m, n). Where m & n have values 1 - 10.

```
F = A1* f(1, 2) + A2* f(2, 3) + A3* f(3, 1) + ....
```

I want to use this F  to form a 2D table such that

```
T = Table[F, {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}]
```

with conditions such that for (i, j)th element of table

```
If i = m && j = n -> f(m, n) = 5, 
If i = n && j = m -> f(m, n) = -5
otherwise f(m, n) = 0
```

To elaborate, for the {2, 3}th element of this table, f(2, 3) should be replaced by 5, f(3, 2) by -5 and other f terms by 0.

How can I do it. Could If function be used with table ?? I could not make it work. Will appreciate any suggestion.. Thanks

Comment: may be I am missing something. But where does `m` and `n` come from in the code you show? And what is `f(f(m, n))`

Comment: f(m, n) is a general representation of components f(1, 2), f(2, 3) etc. Hope it explains...

Comment: but what is `n` and `m` in the code? You show `i` and `j` only.  Are `n` and `m` separate input?

Comment: so in this example you just typed, is `m=1` and `n=2` ?  If so, please edit your question and clarify that `n` and `m` are extra input.

Comment: Yes.. Let me simplify. Lets say f = f(1, 2) + f(1, 3) + f(2, 3). I want to make a 2D table with f such that indices i = 1 - 3 and j = 1 - 3. Now each element of table will represented by a {i, j} set. What I need is that for the element represented by i = 1; j = 2  f(1, 2) = 5 and so on..

Comment: Ok..I can try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> To elaborate, for the {2, 3}th element of this table, f(2, 3) should
>   be replaced by 5, f(3, 2) by -5 and other f terms by 0.

I do not know if this what you want or not

```
ClearAll[f,i,j]
f[i_,j_]/;i<j:=5
f[i_,j_]/;j<i:=-5
f[i_,j_]:=0
(T0=Table[f[i,j],{i,1,10},{j,1,10}])//MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Add per comment below**

> But different constants multiplied to f parameters in F should make
>   sure that elements of matrix are multiple of 5 & -5, not 5 and -5.

To multiply each entry by `A` constant, you need to provide the corresponding
`A` constants to use. Here is an example, using random generated constants.

```
ClearAll[f,i,j]
f[i_,j_]/;i<j:=5 * A0[[i,j]]
f[i_,j_]/;j<i:=-5*A0[[i,j]]
f[i_,j_]:=0
A0=RandomInteger[10,{10,10}];
(T0=Table[f[i,j],{i,1,10},{j,1,10}])//MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update Ref comment**

> Here is a much easier example and expected o/p for F= 5*f(1, 3)+6*f(2,
>   3)+4*f(1, 2) T = Table[F, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]; Should give T = {{
>   5*0+6*0+4*0, 5*0+6*0+4*5, 5*5+6*0+4*0}, { 5*0+6*0+4*(-5), 5*0+6*0+4*0,
>   5*0+6*5+4*0}, { 5*(-5)+6*0+4*0, 5*0+6*(-5)+4*0, 5*0+6*0+4*0}} on
>   simplification – T = {{0, 20, 25}, {-20, 0, 30}. {-25, -30 0}}

Ok, may be this is what you want now? You need a way to specify the constants and the entries they affect. I am still not sure if this is what you want

```
ClearAll[i,j]

(*this A0 encodes the input:  5*f(1, 3)+6*f(2,3)+4*f(1, 2) *)
A0={{5,{1,3}},{6,{2,3}},{4,{1,2}}};

T0=Table[0,{i,1,3},{j,1,3}];
makeEntry[{A0_,{i_,j_}}]:=
      (T0[[i,j]]=If[i<j,5*A0,If[i>j,-5*A0,0]];T0[[j,i]]=-T0[[i,j]]);

makeEntry[#]&/@A0;
MatrixForm[T0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Let me understand it, could be a way forward. But different constants multiplied to f parameters in F should make sure that elements of matrix are multiple of 5 & -5, not 5 and -5.

Comment: @user49535 I added the constants.

Comment: Here is a much easier example and expected o/p for F= 5*f(1, 3)+6*f(2, 3)+4*f(1, 2)
T = Table[F, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
Should give T =  {{ 5*0+6*0+4*0, 5*0+6*0+4*5, 5*5+6*0+4*0}, { 5*0+6*0+4*(-5), 5*0+6*0+4*0, 5*0+6*5+4*0}, { 5*(-5)+6*0+4*0, 5*0+6*(-5)+4*0, 5*0+6*0+4*0}}
on simplification –
T =  {{0, 20, 25}, {-20, 0, 30}. {-25, -30 0}}

Comment: Thanks. if you look this easier ex, for {1, 1} element of matrix - f(1, 3) = f(2, 6) = f(1, 2) = 0. For {1, 2}th element only f(2, 1) = -5, others are 0. For {1, 3}th element f(1, 3) = 5 while others are 0..and so on...

Comment: Thanks, but seems I am not able to explain the problem properly. It is not related to setting different value for f if indices m>n, n> m and n = m. It is about setting different values to a variable in different elements of a table.  Let me try with even easier example. Lets take F = 24 + x. Now if I use Table[F, {i, 1, 3}]. O/P will be {24+x, 24+x, 24+x}. What I want is to give different independent values to x for i = 1, 2 and 3. For ex- If[i == 1, x = 2, If[i == 2, x = 4, If[i == 3, x = 5, 0]]]. Hence the output will be {24+2, 24+4, 24+5} or {26, 28, 29}. Appreciate all help.